# How can I use a coordinate system to get to specific characters in a file, not counting new lines or the first line

Tags: python, coordinates

So I have a coordinate system that points to a position in a large file.

The first line of the file is variable in length (but always starts with a ">" character) and from there the lines are 50 characters long, then a new line. This can go on for several million lines.

I want to be able to find the characters between, for example, 1,000,000-1,000,050 (which would be input at 1000000-1000050) and write these to a string. How can I seek to that position in the file? I tried using f.seek(1000000), but I run in to the problem of the length of the first line. Even if I add the length of the first line to the 1000000 in the f.seek function, I still get an extra character (the newline) for every 50 characters.

The numbers will rarely be as clean as 1000000-1000050.

Comment: You said "I want to be able to find the characters between, for example, 1,000,000-1,000,050". Did you mean *lines*, not *characters*? I don't quite understand the question...

Comment: @BlaXpirit No, I mean characters. Think of it this way: if every character were on one line after the first line, it would be like using the index of a string.

Comment: "I still get an extra character (the newline) for every 50 characters" => you got an answer for your question. So if you want to find range in chars: 1,000,000-1,000,050 then you have to seek len(firstLine) + 1,000,000 + long(1,000,000/50) NOTE: if you got windows `eoln`s, then you got to add 2*long(1,000,000/50)

Comment: @BlaXpirit I want to find the 1 millionth to the 1 millionth and 50th characters, which would be a string of len 50. I never want the newline character.

Comment: @ddzialak ok thats awesome. Can't believe I didn't think of that, I was thinking of mod division and counting lines etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
line_length=50
char_n=10000000 #zero-based index
count=50

with open('f.txt') as f:
    f.readline()
    start=f.tell()
    f.seek(start+int(char_n/line_length)*(line_length+1)+char_n%line_length)
    print(f.read(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using. It seems to work for the small trial I have used.

```
#reads input from user for exon coordinates
coords = raw_input("Please enter the coordinates of the Exon you would like to use\n")

#Reads the first part of coords for the chromosome (and, therefore, filename)
chr_index = coords[:coords.index(":")] + ".fa"

#get starting coordinate
coordStart = coords[coords.index(":")+1:coords.index("-")]

#get ending coordinate
coordEnd = coords[coords.index("-")+1:]

#open the file
f = open(chr_index, "r")

f.seek()
lenFirstLine = len(f.readline())

#create string containing the exon sequence
#move to start of the exon
f.seek(lenFirstLine+coordStart+coordstart/50)

#read the number of characters = to the len of the exon into exon
exon = f.read(coordEnd-coordStart)
```

Comment: For this to make sense, just know that the coordinate system is actually, filename:start-end

Comment: I have run in to the problem of not grabbing the newline character when grabbing a sequence over length 50

Comment: `f.seek()` requires a numeric _offset_ argument and immediately after opening a file the current position is at the first byte. Also, there's no point in doing two of them in a row without something between acting on the file that doesn't leave it positioned at where you want to read from next.

Comment: Are the coordinates being used the number of the desired exon as opposed to the byte offset of the start of one?